# Finding perfect numbers (optimization)

Tags: c#, optimization, number-theory, perfect-numbers

I coded up a program in C# to find perfect numbers within a certain range as part of a programming challenge . However, I realized it is very slow when calculating perfect numbers upwards of 10000. Are there any methods of optimization that exist for finding perfect numbers? My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
 class Program
 {
  public static List<int> FindDivisors(int inputNo)
  {
   List<int> Divisors = new List<int>();
   for (int i = 1; i<inputNo; i++)
   {
    if (inputNo%i==0)
     Divisors.Add(i);
   }
   return Divisors;
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  { 
   const int limit = 100000;

   List<int> PerfectNumbers = new List<int>();
   List<int> Divisors=new List<int>();
   for (int i=1; i<limit; i++)
   {
    Divisors = FindDivisors(i);
    if (i==Divisors.Sum())
     PerfectNumbers.Add(i);
   }

   Console.Write("Output =");

   for (int i=0; i<PerfectNumbers.Count; i++)
   {
    Console.Write(" {0} ",PerfectNumbers[i]);
   }

   Console.Write("\n\n\nPress any key to continue . . . ");
   Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Calculating perfect numbers is like calculating how many days there are in each week. The results never change, so don't calculate them. Look them up.

Comment: @ Daniel Dyson - The poster indicated it was some sort of programming challenge and I doubt he'll be happy with an array of pre-calculated answers =)

Comment: @ paradox - You also have another problem that, because perfect numbers are so sparse, you'll quickly break your int limits if your program goes seriously searching for perfect numbers.

Comment: @Joel Goodwin. That is a fair point, but if I was setting such a challenge to one of my team, I would expect them to come up with the answer that these should be stored and not calculated. After all, the way I read it, the challenge is "to find perfect numbers" not necessarily to "calculate" them. If they have all already been calculated within that range, why calculate them again? Programming is about coming up with the best solution. And that is not always an algorithm.

Comment: @Daniel Dyson. If I needed them in a real world problem, the solutions would definitely be stored - but to me the spirit of this question was "how could you optimise this algorithm?" It's a nasty thing to go searching for, though, as they are spread so thinly, even compared to prime numbers.

Comment: My apologies I tend to only deal in the real world. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the formula

```
testPerfect = 2n-1(2n - 1)
```

to generate possiblities then check wether the number is in fact perfect.

[try this for some bedtime reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

Comment: +1, but note that this wouldn't find any odd perfect numbers (should such numbers exist). Not a problem in this case, though.

Comment: @balpha how did you get the superscript?

Comment: Look at [the source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40788b8d-f2a9-453d-86e9-08c85410eb39/view-source): `<sup>` is one of the whitelisted HTML tags, but you have to use `<pre>` instead of a 4-space-indent code block, since the latter shows HTML tags literally

Comment: I used that generation formula coupled with a check for number % 9 == 1; :) Thanks!

Comment: for those interested about balpha's comment an odd perfect number has a lower bound of 10**1500. If that isn't hard enough to deal with they also have a crazy list of requirements they would need to meet see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Do perfect numbers change? No. [Look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers). Surely, they should be calculated once and then stored.
In your case, the only results will be

```
6
28
496
8128
```

The next one is 33550336. Outside your range.

Answer (score 1):

Just the obvious one from me: you don't need to check every divisor. No point looking for divisors past `inputNo/2`. That cuts down half of the calculations, but this is not an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve things like this involves building a huge array in memory of every number, and then crossing numbers out.

Answer (score 0):

if your still looking for something to calculate perfect numbers.
this goes through the first ten thousand pretty quick, but the 33 million number is a little slower.

```
public class Perfect {
private static Perfect INSTANCE = new Perfect();

public static Perfect getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

/**
 * the method that determines if a number is perfect;
 * 
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public boolean isPerfect(long n) {
    long i = 0;
    long value = 0;
    while(++i<n){
        value = (0 == n%i?value+i:value);
    }
    return n==value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a LINQ based approach, the following method worked quite well and efficiently for me in determining whether or not a caller supplied integer value is a perfect number.

```
bool IsPerfectNumber(int value)
{
    var isPerfect = false;

    int maxCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(value));
    int[] possibleDivisors = Enumerable.Range(1, maxCheck).ToArray();
    int[] properDivisors = possibleDivisors.Where(d => (value % d == 0)).Select(d => d).ToArray();
    int divisorsSum = properDivisors.Sum();

    if (IsPrime(divisorsSum))
    {
        int lastDivisor = properDivisors.Last();
        isPerfect = (value == (lastDivisor * divisorsSum));
    }

    return isPerfect;
}
```

For simplicity and clarity, my implementation for IsPrime(), which is used within IsPerfectNumber(), is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

To continue from Charles Gargent's answer there is a very quick way to check if a Mersenne Number a.k.a. 2^n - 1 is prime. It is called the [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test)
The basic pseudocode though (taken from the Wikipedia page) is:

```
// Determine if Mp = 2p − 1 is prime for p > 2
Lucas–Lehmer(p)
    var s = 4
    var M = 2p − 1
    repeat p − 2 times:
        s = ((s × s) − 2) mod M
    if s == 0 return PRIME else return COMPOSITE
```

Answer (score -3):

ONE-ISN’T-TOO-MANY….

To DISCOVER that there is at-least one ODD perfect-number, and to do so through some mathematical INVENTION.  HISTORICALLY, there WAS a debate as per whether mathematics is INVENTION or DISCOVERY, but as was ABANDONED as a STERILE debate.  NONETHELESS, what IF the outcome of the debate MATTERS?  What IF mathematics IS discovery, than invention, and that our imperfect mathematical inventions (as per perfect-numbers) have prevented us from making mathematical discoveries, but, that if we CORRECT those imperfect inventions through BETTER mathematical inventions we might then DISCOVER a latent mathematical truth, that there is at-least ONE ODD perfect-number?

Let n be any NATURAL number, as can be expressed as the PRODUCT of two other NATURAL numbers a and b, so that n = a x b, where a is less than or equal to b.

So 6 = 1 x 6 or 6 = 2 x 3, but, 6 = 1 x 2 x 3 as NOT considered.

So 8 = 1 x 8 or 8 = 2 x 4, but, 8 = 2 x 2 x 2 as NOT considered.

So perfect-numbers 6 and 28 have the following ordered-pairs, respectively, of associated factors, a and b, of n = 6 or n = 8….(1, 6), (2, 3) for n = 6, and (1, 8), (2, 4) for n = 8.

Whereas the NON-perfect-number 5 has the associated ordered-pair of its two-factors factors (where a is less than or equal to b and a x b = n) as (1, 5), whereas the NON-perfect-number 10 has the associated ordered-pairs of two-factor factors as (1, 10) and (2, 5).

So a perfect-number, such as 6 or 28, as is such that the SUM of its associated ordered-pairs of two-factor factors as equal to 2n.  In other words, 1 + 6 + 2 + 3 = 2 x 6, whereas the SUM of associated ordered-pairs of two-factor factors of 28 as 1 + 28 + 2 + 14 + 4 + 7 = 2 x 28.

Whereas for a NON-perfect-number such as 5 or 10 the SUM of associated ordered-pairs of its two-factor factors as not equal to 2 x 5 nor 2 x 10, respectively.

So a perfect-number, p, as has the SUM of associated ordered-pairs of its two-factors factors as equal to twice the value of p, whereas for NON-perfect-numbers such isn’t the case.

By THIS definition, 1 is a perfect-number as the sum of its ordered-pair of two-factor factors as 1 + 1 = 2 x 1.  1 is then an ODD perfect-number, and as FITS the Euler-Euclid construction as per 1 = (2^(k-1))((2^k)-1) for k = 1.

Comment: What's with the random all uppercase words? Also please don't include personal contact details in your answers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35456801)